# Displaying LISTAGG values in a cell based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on an assignment and I'm very close to finishing however, I have been struggling with one bit of it for a while. I need to display a table that has a SCHEDULE column, and a DAYS column where the DAYS column shows a list of days based on the SCHEDULE. There are only two options for SCHEDULE: 'Weekend' and 'Weekday.'

Here is the end result that I am trying to achieve:

```
ID   Schedule     Days
001  Weekend      Saturday, Sunday
```

I have created a process and am using this code:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE schedules
SET days =
        WHEN schedule = 'Weekend' THEN
        (SELECT LISTAGG(day, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_order)
        FROM days
        WHERE schedule = 'Weekend'
        )
        WHEN schedule = 'Weekday' THEN
        (SELECT LISTAGG(day, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_order)
        FROM days
        WHERE schedule = 'Weekday'
        )
    END
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure

If anyone can give me a hand, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to use `CASE` expression? If yes then you miss one `CASE` and one `END` keyword. If no then your query syntax is wrong.

Comment: Use the comma separated values only for display. Don't store them in the table.

Comment: Why are you using `UPDATE`?

Comment: I am using update because it is a process and I need the days column to display values. I see what you're all saying about storing values. What is another way I can go about this tehn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update is equivalent to this.

```
UPDATE schedules s 
SET    days = (SELECT LISTAGG(day, ', ') 
                        within group ( ORDER BY day_order ) 
               FROM   days d 
               WHERE  d.schedule IN ( 'Weekend', 'Weekday' ) 
                      AND d.schedule = s.schedule 
               GROUP  BY d.schedule ) ;
```

But, I would **not recommend** this. Storing the records as comma separated values is bound to cause problems for you in future. Only use it to display the results using a query like below. This assumes that in your days table, there are  unique rows for each day.If there are duplicates, `join` it to the distinct result set from days.

```
SELECT d.id, 
       d.schedule, 
       LISTAGG(s.day, ', ') 
         within GROUP ( ORDER BY d.day_order ) 
FROM   days d 
       join schedules s 
         ON ( d.schedule = s.schedule ) 
WHERE  d.schedule IN ( 'Weekend', 'Weekday' ) 
GROUP  BY d.id, 
          d.schedule
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used the update command you provided and it was valid. I should mention that I am using Oracle APEX and that in order to join these two tables there is a third table that goes in between.

Comment: The days table links to a SCHEDULE_DAY table via the Day_ID, then  SCHEDULE_DAY links to SCHEDULE via SCHEDULE_ID. (Not my choice, how the assignment was set up). I did edit your code to accommodate.

Comment: I realize now what you meant with the problem of storing vs displaying. Is there a way to simply display it in a table? That is what I have been trying to achieve but with no luck.

Comment: @HassanNaveed :  You're welcome. I hope this question answers the question in your original post. If you found this answer useful, please vote or accept the answer. If you have further problems to solve, post that as  a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO schedules dst
USING (
  SELECT schedule,
         LISTAGG( day, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY day_order ) AS days
  FROM   days
  GROUP BY schedule
) src
ON ( dst.schedule = src.schedule )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET days = src.days;
```

But you would probably be better to not store values in a delimited list and just use a foreign key reference between `schedules.schedule` and `days.schedule` to connect the two tables.

Comment: I tried creating a foreign key but it would not allow me to do so. I used the above solution to do it.