# Displaying listagg values based on values in another column (part 2)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I posted a similar question previously here: [Displaying LISTAGG values in a cell based on the value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365445/displaying-listagg-values-in-a-cell-based-on-the-value-of-another-column).

In that question, I was using UPDATE to store a comma delimited list.

I got a solution for that but I realized thanks to the contributors, that this is not the best way to do so.

I am using Oracle APEX and need to display this data in a table.

```
ID   Schedule     Days
001  Weekend      Saturday, Sunday
```

I have 3 tables to work with. They are, for simplicity, DAYS, SCHEDULES and DAY_SCHEDULES.

```
DAYS table
Day_ID - PK
Day_Order
Day_Name
Schedule (I added this column myself, the others were already provided)

SCHEDULES table
Schedule_ID - PK
Schedule (only two possible values: 'Weekend' or 'Weekday')
Days
Several other columns but not relevant

DAY_SCHEDULES table
Day_schedules_id - PK
Schedule_ID - FK
Day_ID - FK
```

I have tried several ways to make the Days column display a list of the corresponding days but none seem to work. My main attempts have been fiddling with SELECT/CASE statements but it still will not display anything even when the syntax is all correct.

I cannot make an FK between the two tables as neither Schedules column is unique.

I am not sure what to try next so any help or tips are appreciated!

Thank you,

Hassan

Comment: Post some sample data from the tables and then the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve (you do not need the `DAYS` column in the schedule table as you can calculate it from the days table):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c415f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DAYS ( Day_ID, Day_Order, Day_Name, Schedule ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       LEVEL - 1,
       TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + LEVEL - 1,
         'FMDay',
         'NLS_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
       ),
       CASE
       WHEN LEVEL <= 5
       THEN 'Weekday'
       ELSE 'Weekend'
       END
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;

CREATE TABLE SCHEDULES ( Schedule_ID, Schedule, Other ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Weekend', 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Weekday', 'DEF' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s.*,
       d.days
FROM   schedules s
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT schedule,
                LISTAGG( day_name, ', ' )
                  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY day_order ) AS days
         FROM   days
         GROUP BY schedule ) d
       ON ( s.schedule = d.schedule )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c415f/1/0)**:

```
| SCHEDULE_ID | SCHEDULE | OTHER |                                         DAYS |
|-------------|----------|-------|----------------------------------------------|
|           2 |  Weekday |   DEF | Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday |
|           1 |  Weekend |   ABC |                             Saturday, Sunday |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are correct, your results is exactly what I am trying to achieve. 
Will this function in Oracle APEX though? Also, the schema has already been set up. If I implement just the query, should it work, in theory?  You do not have any columns that are not available to me. I am hesitant though due to the lack of IF/CASE statements in the query. I can see that you've already defined the 'Weekday', 'Weekend' relationship in the schema set up. I am wondering how it will function in APEX.

Comment: I implemented the query and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!